# Can I use the Tor-Browser-Bundle update my ubuntu or it may be a bad idea?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, ubuntu

I'm really enjoying using this software, but would like to upgrade my ubuntu by network tor with TBB using the command `apt-get update` and `upgrade`. I need advice if this is possible or compromise my operating system to a serious security risk. Updating the conventional way is too risky for me, because my ISP monitors me, my internet only works with proxy restrictive. I need to install the free software that I would question why I need them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I do a download via TBB safely?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/820/can-i-do-a-download-via-tbb-safely)

Comment: No, I don't think it's a duplicate. http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/820/can-i-do-a-download-via-tbb-safely is about downloading a file using TBB and this one is about how to obtain operating system updates using TBB. (Sure, internally it's all just files, but downloading using TBB is a very different interface and threat model than updating using apt-get.) I would suggest to rephrase that questions to "How to update my system using apt-get over Tor (using TBB)"?

Comment: If your ISP monitors you downloading TBB then he will also notice you downloading it via `apt-get`. How about [using a mirror of the Tor site](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/mirrors.html.en)?

Answer (score 4):

If you only used signed repositories for your software, then you should be fine.  Both Debian and Ubuntu sign their archives by default, and apt complains as soon as you add an insecure source to its list.  Thus, it should not matter how you download the packages - their integrity gets verified by the system before installing and everything should be secure.

To use Tor to update your system or install packages it's probably better to just install the tor packages from [deb.torproject.org](http://deb.torprojects.org/) - see [the docs on the Tor-website](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian) for installation instructions.

Once the package is installed, you should be able to run commands such as these in a root shell:

```
# torify apt-get update
# torify apt-get install ri-li
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is about performing apt-get over the Tor network through TBB.

What you need to do is [configure your apt to use a proxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy). The proxy is localhost:9150 by default.

Not tried this myself so no guarantees.

Comment: This does not answer the main question - if it is a good idea.