# How can I force terminal to use Tor on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, censorship, torsocks, terminal, torify

I wanted to install a program on terminal but it's blocked. How do I torfiy my terminal to fetch the package over Tor?

Comment: It will probably be easier to (try to) torify the tool you're trying to use inside the terminal, rather than the terminal itself. What command are you trying to use for the install?

Comment: Trying to install jdk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this using `apt-get`, rather than building from source, you can use torify in the following way:

```
# torify apt-get update
# torify apt-get install <jdk_packages>
```

[A similar solution was offered here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/839/1730]

Comment: If just the package download process needs to be torified you can try [apt-transport-tor](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt-transport-tor), and change http in the sources.list to tor+http.

Answer (score 1):

You can send any command over Tor with `torify` or `torsocks`.

Example:

```
torsocks wget https://path/to/file
```

or

```
torify apt-get update
```

or

```
torsocks git clone https://path/to/git
```

or even ssh, scp or sftp over Tor

```
torsocks ssh user@host
```